# What does this symbol mean in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define result (assoc n cache))
(cond
  [result => second]
  [else ...])
```

What does the `=>` mean? I'm guessing it runs `second` on `result` and returns the value? What is this called and where can I find out more about this?

Comment: Maybe [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=%3D%3E#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause `[result => second]` is handled like this by `cond`:

1. The expression result is evaluated and the result is stored in a temporary variable, say, `t`.
2. If the value was non-false, then the expression `second` is evaluated and the result is stored in, say, `f`.
3. If the the value `f` is a function, then `(f t)` is evaluated and its result becomes the result of the `cond` expression.
4. If `f` is not a function, an error is signaled.

The expansion of

```
(cond
  [result => second]
  [else something])
```

is something like

```
(let ()
  (define t result)
    (if t (second t)
        something))))
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it means the same as

```
(cond (result (second result))
      (else ...))
```

In general, a cond clause of

```
(foo => bar)
```

means that if `foo` evaluates to a truthy value, then its value is saved, and passed as an argument to `bar` (which should evaluate to a procedure that takes one argument).

Answer (score 2):

That means: if the condition evaluates to a truthy value, send that value to the function to the right. It's in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._~3d~3e%29%29). For example:

```
(define alst '((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)))

; if the list contains an association with the `y` key, return the second element
; of that association, which happens to be the value `2`
(cond ((assoc 'y alst) => second)
      (else #f))
=> 2
```